# Why don't we solve vanishing/exploding gradients problem just by normalizing the gradients?

Tags: neural-networks

For example, suppose after a mini-batch, we calculated the gradient is [0.00003, 0.00001, 0.0000006], whice is too small, gradient is vanishing.

Why don't we solve this problem just by dividing the calculated gradient by its L2 norm? I think knowing the direction of the gradient is enough, we do not care its magnitude, we can normalize its magnitude. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Rprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Normalising gradients results in effectively increasing the learning rate based on gradient norm which will almost certainly lead to overstepping local and global minima, leading the network to not learn anything useful.

Instead of normalising the gradients you can instead normalise the weight matrix of each hidden unit post gradient update at each step. This explicitly prevents dying or exploding gradients by enforcing the signal energy remains at a relatively normalised level as it propagates forwards and backwards.

Combining weight normalisation with a technique like L1 regularisation will force the weight matrix to maximise important connections while minimising irrelevant ones.

---

#### Edit: additional clarification of effects of normalised gradients

To illustrate mathematically what happens I'll take a simpler example of stochastic gradient descent for a linear model. Given gradients $g_t$, learning rate $\alpha$ and model parameters $\theta_t$ the update rule is as follows:
$$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t - \alpha g_t$$

Now, if we normalised the gradients our update rule would be written as:
$$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t - \frac{\alpha}{||g_t||} g_t$$
So we are effectively modifying the learning rate by the norm of the gradients. When the gradients are small $||g_t||<1$ and as such the learning rate will be increased. Increasing the learning rate can result in overstepping minima, as illustrated by this diagram:

[image: Effects of learning rates]

Equally, if the gradients are large $||g_t||>1$ and as such the learning rate will decrease, and as shown in the diagram it will converge slowly and may never reach minima in reasonable time.

Comment: “Normalising gradients results in effectively increasing the learning rate based on gradient norm which will almost certainly lead to overstepping local and global minima”，why？

Comment: @MikeMathcook I have updated my answer with additional clarification

Comment: Your diagram is great! However, my confusion is still there. Suppose you are walking from NewYork to Paris, the only tool you have is a compass, then you walk 100 meters and ask your compass which direction you should go. You do this iterately and you will arrive Paris. You only need it tells you which direction to go, you do not need it tell you how long you should go to that direction. Meanwhile, it does not know how long you should go. That is exactly what a gradient tells you, it only tells you the direction. I think the length of the calculated gradient encodes nothing, so it sho

Comment: My reply is too long, so I moved it to an answer post. Please check it.

Comment: That makes th assumption that your compass is reliable. But it isnt. This is due to a few things: firstly the problem is non-convex, i.e. there isn't only just one global minima, there are also local minima that are non optimal; and secondly due to computing gradients in batches as opposed to over the entire dataset your gradient is only partly representative of the direction towards a minima. For a linear problem like linear regression you can get to the global minima in exactly one step by effectively normalising the gradient and solving it as a quadratic form.

Answer (score 0):

We use the gradient to know exactly how much to adjust our parameters. So I believe that if you normalised the vanishing gradient you would overshoot the optimal values and likely end up with worse estimates. But I could be wrong, I haven't touched this for a while

Comment: You can overshoot, yes. Or you can have such a small resulting step size for some parameters that they never update appropriately.